# Yii 2 как подключить Sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite, yii2

файл sqlite.db (создан SqliteBrowser) в корне сайта

настройки

```
     return [
             'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:' . __DIR__  .'/../../sqlite.db',
```

pdo_sqlite подключен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

положить файл в `yii2.site\config`

путь `'dsn' => 'sqlite:'.__DIR__ . '/sqlite.db',`

Answer (score 3):

В корень приложения 'dsn' => 'sqlite:@app/sqlite.db'

Answer (score 0):

Покажу на примере advanced приложения.

В файле:

```
app/common/config/main-local.php
```

нужно изменить 'db' следующим образом:

```
'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'sqlite:'. realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../'))."/sqlite.db",
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'enableSchemaCache' => true,
        ],
```

при этом файл базы размещаем в корень приложения.

Или можно добавить как вторую базу не меняя при этом дефолтную базу 'db':

```
'dbSqlite' => [
                'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
                'dsn' => 'sqlite:'. realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../'))."/sqlite.db",
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'enableSchemaCache' => true,
            ],
```

При добавлении как вторую базу в модели можем подключиться следующим образом:

```php
class YourModelName extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->dbSqlite;
    }

    static public function tableName()
    {
        return "{{%your_table_name}}";
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            // ...
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```